# Have to input values as insert in signup and matching the values with inserted using login in laravel 4.2

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-4

Hi guys able to simple validate the login details and signup details but unable to insert and fetch database of phpmyadmin using laravel 4.2.
Can you help with this?

Following is my code for models

```
class Website extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface 
{ 
use UserTrait,RemindableTrait;
protected $table = 'websites'; 
protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');
protected $protected = array();
protected $fillable = array('name',email','username','password','confirm_password','phone');
}
```

here is code for view file

here is view file

signup.blade.php

```
                                                {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'register')) }}    
                                                            @if($errors->has('name'))
                                                                    {{ $errors->first('name') }}
                                                                @endif                      
                                                            {{ Form::label('name', 'Name:') }}
                                                            {{ Form::text('name')  }}



                                                             @if($errors->has('username'))
                                                                    {{ $errors->first('username') }}
                                                                @endif
                                                            {{ Form::label('username', 'Username:') }}
                                                            {{ Form::text('username') }}

                                                            @if($errors->has('password'))
                                                                    {{ $errors->first('password') }}
                                                                @endif
                                                            {{ Form::label('password', 'Password:') }}
                                                                {{ Form::password('password') }}

                                                            @if($errors->has('password'))
                                                                    {{ $errors->first('confirm_password') }}
                                                                                @endif
                                                            {{ Form::label('password', 'Confirm Password:') }}
                                                            {{ Form::password('confirm_password') }}

                                                            @if($errors->has('email'))
                                                                                {{ $errors->first('email') }}
                                                                                                @endif
                                                            {{ Form::label('email', 'Email:') }}
                                                                {{ Form::text('email')  }}


                                                            @if($errors->has('phone'))
                                                                                    {{ $errors->first('phone') }}
                                                                                    @endif
                                                            {{ Form::label('phone', 'Phone:') }}
                                                            {{ Form::text('phone') }}


                                                            </div>

                                                        {{ Form::submit('Create', array('class' => 'btn btn-success')) }}


                {{ Form::close() }}
```

here is login.blade.php

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'login')) }}
  <table>
     <tr>

        <td width="150px" class="table-responsive">
            {{ Form::label('username', 'Username:') }}
            {{ Form::text('username') }}
             @if($errors->has('username'))
                          <label> {{  $errors->first('username') }} </label>
             @endif
       </td>
        </tr>   
        <tr>
          <td width="150px">
            {{ Form::label('password', 'Password:') }}
            {{ Form::text('password') }}
            @if($errors->has('password'))
                          <label> {{  $errors->first('password') }} </label>
             @endif
        </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
          <td width="150px">
        <div class="field">
            <input type="checkbox" name="remember"  id="remember"> 
            <label for="remember"> 
                Remember me
                </td>
        </tr>
        </div>
        <tr>
        <td>
            {{ Form::submit('Login', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}
       </td>
</tr>
</table>    
@if( $errors->count() > 0 )
    <p>The following errors have occurred:</p>

    <ul id="form-errors">
        {{ $errors->first('username', '<li>:message</li>') }}
        {{ $errors->first('password', '<li>:message</li>') }}
        {{ $errors->first('password_confirmation', '<li>:message</li>') }}
    </ul>   
@endif{{ Form::close() }}
```

here is my code for controller for function

WebsiteController.php

```
<?php

    class WebsiteController extends BaseController {

            public function index()
                        {
                            return View::make('websites.index',compact('websites'));
                        }


            public function login()
                        {

                             return View::make('websites.login');

                        }
            public function signup()
                        {

                                return View::make('websites.signup');

                        }


            public function show()
                        {
                                                 $input=Input::all();
                                                 $messages = array('username.required' => 'Please enter your username','password.required' => 'You have to set a password');
                                                 $rules = array(  'username'  => 'required|alpha-num','password'  => 'required');
                                                 $validator = Validator::make($input,$rules,$messages);

                                    if ($validator->fails()) {
                                                                      print_r($input);
                                                                      echo 1;
                                                                      return Redirect::to('login')->withErrors($validator);

                                                             }


                                                        else
                                                             {
                                                                  return Redirect::to('websites')
                                                                  ->with('message', 'Your account has been created, please login');                                                                   print_r($input);      
                                                             }



                     }
            public function store()
            {

                        $input=Input::all();

                         $messages = array(
                                                            'name.required' => 'Please enter your name',
                                                            'email.required' => 'your email address required',
                                                            'username.required' => 'Please enter your username',
                                                            'password.required' => 'You have to set a password',
                                                            'confirm_password.required' => 'Write again your password',
                                                            'confirm_password.matchpass' => 'The two passwords does not match');

                                  $rules = array(
                                                            'name'=>'required|alpha',                     
                                                            'username'  => 'required|alpha-num',
                                                            'password'  => 'required',
                                                            'confirm_password'=>'required',
                                                            'email'     => 'required|email',
                                                            'phone'=>'required|numeric'
        );


                         $validator = Validator::make($input,$rules,$messages);

                                    if ($validator->fails()) {
                                                                  print_r($input);

                                                                echo 1;
                                                                 return Redirect::to('register')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();

                                    }
                                                        else
                                                             {
                                                                        $user = new Website();
                                                                        $user->username =$input['username'];
                                                                        $user->email = $input['email'];
                                                                        $user->password = $input['password'];
                                                                        $user->name = $input['name'];
                                                                        $user->phone =$input['phone'];

                                                                        return Response::json(array('success' => true), 200);
                                                                        return Redirect::to('login')
                   ->with('global', 'Your account has been created! We have sent an email to activate your account');
//                                                                      }

                                                                                                                                    }


        }

        }
?>
```

Comment: Wheres your code ? what did you do so far ?

Comment: where is your code for inserting or selecting from the db ?

Comment: i added that code controller and unable to do it so please expalin how to proceed

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot to `save` the data in the `store` method.

Add:

```
$user->save();
```

To:

```
$user = new Website();
$user->username =$input['username'];
$user->email = $input['email'];
$user->password = $input['password'];
$user->name = $input['name'];
$user->phone =$input['phone'];
```

Final result:

```
$user = new Website();
$user->username =$input['username'];
$user->email = $input['email'];
$user->password = $input['password'];
$user->name = $input['name'];
$user->phone =$input['phone'];
$user->save();
```

To get all the result in your `index method` you need to add this code before the return:

```
$websites = Website::all();
```

Final result:

```
public function index()
{
    $websites = Website::all();
    return View::make('websites.index',compact('websites'));
}
```

Plus you have an error in your `model`, at this line you're missing an `apostrophe`, this is correct:

```
protected $fillable = array('name','email','username','password','confirm_password','phone');
```